# 1000 Day "Anniversary"

Tags: single-word-requests, etymology, latin

"Anniversary" comes from Latin: "anni" [genitive of *annus* = year] + "vers(us)" [past participle of *vertere* = to turn]. I am interested in constructing a similar word which means "reoccurring every 1000 days".

"One thousand", in Latin, is *mille* and the genitive plural of "day" is *dierum*. Hence: mille-dierum-versary. However, this doesn't sound brilliant -- I know very little about Latin, so am not sure how its affixation works -- so does anyone have any better suggestions?

Comment: How about just *milleversary*?

Comment: You could just call it a 'thousand-day anniversary', and people won't bat an eye. It may not be technically correct, but your meaning will be understood.  Better understood than creating a word based on the two that would take some interpreting and could mislead someone into thinking you mean something entirely different.

Comment: How about _milledierum celebration_?

Comment: There is no reason not to use the word 'anniversary'. Merriam-Webster gives "broadly : a date that follows such an event by a specified period of time measured in units other than years *the 6-month anniversary of the accident*" in sense 1 for [*anniversary*](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/anniversary)

Comment: 1,000th-day anniversary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Urban Dictionary lists an obvious choice: *[kiloversary](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=kiloversary)*, also known as *k-day*.

(Coming soon to a Hallmark card near you.)

Comment: I'm quite liking "k-day": I think I'll go with that :)

Comment: If it's celebrating 1,000 days of some bacteria surviving in a petri dish, Kiloversary sounds alright, but if you're celebrating 1,000 days together with a loved one, `milleversary` sounds so much better. Mille is the French word for thousand and comes from Latin whereas kilo- comes from greek and sounds far more technical and scientific... 

Same for 100, btw. I'd take centennial over hectonnial ( from the Greek *hekaton* for 100 )

Answer (score 4):

I would use 1,000 day **commemoration** to celebrate something that is not in years.

Answer (score 3):

> In Italian it is "millesimo giorno".

http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/M/millesimo.shtml

> It should be "thousandth day".

"That tradition is celebrating its thousandth day"

http://www.thefreedictionary.com/thousandth

Comment: OP was looking for a word to mean *thousandth day anniversary* not for a repetition of the question. Although the Italian link was interesting, so no downvote. :)

Answer (score -1):

**M-day**

Because *M* = Roman numeral for 1000

Comment: I don't know why this post was downvotes. M of course stands for Mille (thousand), and it's a pretty good answer, especially considering we call 1,000 years a millenium and use M on monuments to signify the a point in time: MCMXVIII anyone?

Answer (score -2):

> ## Milleversary

Although I don't think a word exists in common usage I wouldn't hesitate to use **Milleversary**.

While The Greek root work *kilo-* could be used, when it comes to the passage of time, Latin root words are more commonly used.

*Mille* is the latin word ( and French and Italian spelling ) for 1,000. and we use it with the other popular time-related word: Millennium. We also use the Latin *centum* for 100 (in century and centennial) rather than the Greek *hekaton*.

By way of contrast, we use the greek prefixes *kilo-* and *hecto-* often in weights and measures.

- A hectare is 100m x 100m
- Kilogram, kilometre, kilopascal

Additionally, we often use Roman numerals to signify or demarcate points in time. **M** means 1,000 in Roman numerals. You see MCMXVIII all over Europe on monuments erected referring to WWI, like the [Welsh National War Memorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welsh_National_War_Memorial) which has on it MCMXIV–MCMXVIII on its outer frieze.

You used to see Copyright marks all the time using roman numberals as well, like  ©MCMLXXIV (before 2000 mostly, as ©MMI is a little odd-looking I'd imagine).

French still extensively uses Roman numerals to refer to centuries. *Xe* is often used to mean the *10th century* or *dixième siècle*.

The very passage of time on a clock is STILL very often marked in roman numerals, from I to XII. For these reasons, I'd definitely say *milleversary* sounds more natural than something like *kiloversary* if it's anything beyond measuring how many days a bacterial strain has survived inside a petri dish.